# I want to create an invisible GridView to be coordinates on my screen

Tags: java, android, xml, gridview, coordinates

so I am working on an app, using Android Studio, and I want to basically have 3 layouts. The first being a static background linear layout, that will only have a picture that is the background. Above that, is another Linear layout, that will have "nothing", and above that is an invisible grid layout, that each "box" has two numbers, rows, and columns, and Using that, I will know where to put stuff in my second Linear layout(E.g, If i want to move something to the top right, I will just put in the position 0,0 and it will put it on that position, but on the linear layout, rather than the grid layout.)

I already made the gridlayout, and the linear layouts, here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map_backround"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/grassGreen"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/greenBackround" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/mapPosition">
    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_hardcore"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:columnWidth="4dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="0dp"
        android:numColumns="270"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="0dp"
        android:visibility="invisible">
    </GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

And The baseAdapter. Take in mind, class Map is basically a Class that inherits Coordination, and has a 2d array of coordinates (creating a 2d map of coordinates), And coordinates is just a class with 2 integers, one for rows and one for columns, giving me an id for each square.

```
public class gridViewHandler extends BaseAdapter
{
    Context context;
    private Map selectedMap;
    private Coordination[][] position;
    private int countLocations;
    public gridViewHandler(Context context, Map selectedMap)
    {
        this.countLocations = 0;
        this.context = context;
        this.selectedMap = selectedMap;
        this.position = selectedMap.getMapParams();
        for(int i = 0; i < selectedMap.getColumns(); i++)
        {
            for(int a = 0; a < selectedMap.getRows(); a++)
            {
                countLocations++;
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return countLocations;
    }
    public int getColumnCount()
    {
        return position.length;
    }
    public int getRowCount()
    {
        return position[0].length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int colNum, int rowNum)
    {
        return position[colNum][rowNum];
    }
    @Override
    public  Object getItem(int i)
    {
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Lastly, Here is what my "Main_Activity" looks like(I called it game)

```
public class Game extends Activity {

    private GridView defaultMap;
    private Map map = new Map();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        defaultMap = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.map_hardcore);
        gridViewHandler gridAdapter = new gridViewHandler(Game.this, map);
        defaultMap.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
    }
}
```

So, I don't really know how I can use what I already made. I think that the gridview is ready, and all I need to do is create the two linear layouts, then create the function where I insert the ID of the gridview box(rows,cols) and an item, and it will display it on the linear layout in that position. Any Idea how I can implement this?

My goal to achieve is a map where I will always be able to know, and control where every object is.

Comment: Can you please describe **what** you try to achieve and not only **how**?

Comment: Yes. I want to achieve a map, that has coordinates, so I can control and know exactly where every object is in every moment.